# Is ODP.NET redistributable?

Tags: .net, oracle, licensing, odp.net

Are the Oracle ODP.NET libraries redistributable? As in, can I simply include the Oracle.DataAccess.dll with my application & reference it without getting into any legal hot water? The download license for the ODAC on OTN is fairly incomprehesible legalese that doesn't make it clear whether I can or can't include the dll directly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked to a lawyer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to distribute is the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/oci/instantclient/index.html).  This is a freely distributable Oracle component that contains the files you need for client applications and nothing else.

Personally I've never never used it with ODP.NET but there is [an article about using Instant Client and ODP.NET on the Oracle website](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/08-nov/o68odpnet.html).  I have used the Instant Client for Java and Perl applications with no problems.

Comment: But can I include the ODP.NET dll with my app without the user having to run a separate installer from oracle?

Comment: The Instant Client is a ZIP of files so I don't think there is an installer as such.  The thing to check is if there is a licence agreement attached to the Instant Client; if there is you probably have to distribute that too.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle now publishes a "redist package". It's called "ODAC (Oracle Data Access Components) with xcopy". This includes the ODP drivers, the instant client, and all supporting unmanaged DLLs required.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

Comment: It's now very simple, one managed DLL (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll).  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E48297_01/doc/win.121/e41125/installODPmd.htm#BABCEJBI.