# Adding Oracle driver to C# program

Tags: c#, windows, oracle, jar, driver

I just finished up a Windows service in C# that queries an Oracle database. It works fine if the Oracle Client software is installed on the server it runs on, but we don't want to have to install that software on every server just to run this app. Is there a way I can package the .jar file into my program so that it won't have to rely on a huge installation every time? Thanks.

Comment: Check out this thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685511/is-odp-net-redistributable

Comment: Have you looked into whether you need the client at all?

Look at this thread -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935808/how-can-i-deploy-a-net-application-that-uses-odac-without-installing-the-whole

Comment: the xcopy deployment comes with the instant client.  You'll need to setup your env correctly to use it.  Also, I'm assuming as a service, you won't need to worry about too many installations anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use beta or can wait then Oracle should release soon [full managed driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbeta-1696432.html) that doesn't require Oracle Client. It is API compatible with existing provider but have some [limitations](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/odpmbetainstall-1696475.html#Differences).